# How can I get copied text from clipboard in my jest test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, clipboard

I try to test my React app with Jest.

I have a button that copies text to the clipboard. (this text is generated in my App, the user can't see it on the screen)

I want to test this copied text with reference text. How can I get copied text from the clipboard in my test?

React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import useClipboard from 'react-use-clipboard';

function FileLoader() {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);

  const dataForHtml = `<img src="${state.png}" alt="banner" />`;

  const [isCopiedHtml, setCopiedHtml] = useClipboard(dataForHtml);

  return (
        <button className="btn" onClick={setCopiedHtml}>
          Save
        </button>
  );
}

export default FileLoader;
```

The beginning of my test:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import FileLoader from '../src/components/FileLoader/FileLoader';



describe('save btns', () => {
  const initialState = {
    png: 'some_img_url'
  },
  const mockStore = configureStore()
  let store

  it('should save html', () => {
    store = mockStore(initialState)
    const { getByText } = render(<Provider store={store}><FileLoader /></Provider>)
    const saveHtmlBtn = screen.findByText('html');
    saveHtmlBtn.then((save) => {
      userEvent.click(save)
      

    });
  })
})
```

Comment: do you have any code you have tried?

Comment: Please provide the code you have.

Comment: Added react component code